# Making requests to Google API using Guzzle and Socialite in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, google-api, google-oauth, guzzle, laravel-socialite

I'm building a web app that has to interact with Google Contacts API and retrieve the Contact List of the authenticated user, but I'm getting

```
ClientException in RequestException.php line 89:
Client error response [url] https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/ambermphatic@gmail.com/full?prettyPrint=false [status code] 403 [reason phrase] Forbidden
```

Here's my AuthenticateUser.php where I have included the getContactList function, I'm trying to make the Guzzle Request to the Google Server and managed to send the correct access token by storing it in a session variable, but I'm still getting a forbidden response :

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Laravel\Socialite\Contracts\Factory as Socialite;
use App\Repositories\UserRepository;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;


class AuthenticateUser {

    /**
     * @var UserRepository
     */
    private $users;
    /**
     * @var Socialite
     */
    private $socialite;
    /**
     * @var Guard
     */
    private $guard;

    private $token;

    public function __construct(UserRepository $users, Socialite $socialite, Guard $guard)
    {

        $this->users = $users;
        $this->socialite = $socialite;
        $this->guard = $guard;
    }


    /**
     * @param $hasCode
     * @param AuthenticateUserListener $listener
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function execute($hasCode, AuthenticateUserListener $listener)
    {

        if ( ! $hasCode ) return $this->getAuthorizationFirst();

        $var = $this->getGoogleUser();

        $user = $this->users->findByUsernameOrCreate($var);

        \Session::put('token', $var->token );

        \Auth::login($user, true);

        return $listener->userHasLoggedIn($user);

    }

    public function logout()
    {

        \Auth::logout();

        return redirect('/');


    }

    private function getAuthorizationFirst()
    {

        return \Socialize::with('google')->redirect();

    }

    private function getGoogleUser()
    {

        return \Socialize::with('google')->user();
    }

    public function getContactList()
    {

        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

        $email = \Auth::user()->email;

        $token = \Session::get('token');

        $json = $client->get('https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/'. $email . '/full', [
            'query' => [
                'prettyPrint' => 'false',
            ],
            'headers' => [
                'Accept' => 'application/json',
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token ,
            ],
        ]);

        dd($json);

        return $json;

    }
}
```

Here's my AuthController.php

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\AuthenticateUser;
use App\AuthenticateUserListener;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Laravel\Socialite\Two\GoogleProvider as Google;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AuthController extends Controller implements AuthenticateUserListener
{

    public function login(AuthenticateUser $authenticateUser, Request $request){

       return $authenticateUser->execute($request->has('code'), $this);
    }

    public function userHasLoggedIn($user)
    {

        return redirect('/');
    }

    public function logout(AuthenticateUser $authenticateUser){


        return $authenticateUser->logout();

    }

    public function getContactList(AuthenticateUser $authenticateUser)
    {
        $response = $authenticateUser->getContactList();

        dd($response);
    }
}
```

Here's my MainController.php

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class MainController extends Controller {


    public function index()
    {
        if (\Auth::check()) return redirect('google_welcome');
        return redirect('google_login');
    }

    public function first()
    {
        return view('google_login');
    }

    public function back()
    {
        $user = \Auth::user();
        return view('google_welcomeback')->with('user', $user);
    }

}
```

I'm fairly new to the PHP and Laravel universe, what's with trying to immediately use Google APIs and packages such as socialite which is using oAuth 2. I have really struggled to make the most out of my limited knowledge and haven't really found much documentation online, and the problem is my employer hinted that I either have to complete this as fastly as possible or he's gonna show me the way out...

Comment: Did you manage to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to get by and finally got past that error, changing my getContactList function to the following and adding the proper scope :

```
 public function getContactList()
    {
        $config = [
            'client_id' => env('CLIENT_ID', ''),
            'client-secret' => env('CLIENT_SECRET', ''),
        ];

        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client($config);

        $email = \Auth::user()->email;

        $token = \Session::get('token');

        $json = $client->get('https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/',  [

            'headers' => [

                'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token,

            ],
        ]);

        dd($json);

        return $json;
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the very same problem today. Debugging Socialite I've found out that there's a problem with get authorization token call to google.

In the end it turned out to be just client secret copy-pasted wrongly to configuration.

To discover real source of problem, you can try following command:

```
curl -v -d grant_type=authorization_code -d client_id="<YOUR_ID_HERE>" -d client_secret="<YOUR_SECRET_HERE>" -d code="<CODE_HERE>" -d redirect_uri="<YOUR_CALLBACK_URI_HERE>" https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
```

Client ids/secrets/uris you already have and code can be obtained with debugger or adding some debug print in ./vendor/laravel/socialite/src/Two/GoogleProvider.php - for example in getAccessToken($code) method.

For me it resulted in real answer:

```
{
  "error" : "invalid_client",
  "error_description" : "The OAuth client was not found."
}
```

Once you fix this there's another caveat that's not documented - Socialite needs your Google app to have Google+ API enabled. This can be done at: https://console.developers.google.com

Comment: thanks for sharing this information. had the same error, enabling g+ api has solved the error