# How to do Google backend authentication of access token in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, google-authentication

I want to perform Google's backend verification in Laravel. Sorry about the confusion.

I want to get the access-token of the user validated by Google.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Socialite is from the Laravel dev team, is there any reason why you don't want to use it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use cURL or Guzzle and manually authenticate with the Google API.

Answer (score 1):

You should accept Alex Cobb's answer as it is correct. But since it is so short:
Someone else had a guzzle/socialite question similar, and has an acceptable excerpt for the code:
[Making requests to Google API using Guzzle and Socialite in Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29342470/making-requests-to-google-api-using-guzzle-and-socialite-in-laravel-5)

And just in case you require Guzzle information:
http://www.pixelite.co.nz/article/guzzle-http-post-authentication-and-form-submission-symfony-20/

which shows how guzzle is the PHP solution in making curl call.

**IMPORTANT NOTE:**

why reinvent the wheel, laravel does this out of the box with socialite:

> Laravel Socialite Introduction
>
> Laravel Socialite provides an expressive, fluent interface to OAuth
>   authentication with Facebook, Twitter, Google, LinkedIn, GitHub and
>   Bitbucket. It handles almost all of the boilerplate social
>   authentication code you are dreading writing.

https://github.com/laravel/socialite